# Cannot set any controls to be transparent in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

EDIT: I tested this with other controls, and they all seem to be unable to have transparency.
I am using .net framework 4.5.2 
When I set the .BackColor property of any control to Color.Transparent, they all show up as the same color as the background but I cannot see any controls under them. For example, I cannot make PictureBox transparent.

I've been trying everything to make a chart transparent (so I can see controls under it)

This is for `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting`.

I tried setting both the background and the foreground and the chart areas background and secondary background to transparent, but the chart is still the same color as the windows form (grayish-white).

From what I read online, it's sufficient to set the background of the chart and chartArea0 (which is my only chart area)

As such:

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
chart.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("ChartArea1"));
chart.ChartAreas[0].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Please let me know what I can do to make it transparent.

Comment: Are You sure it is not transparent?

Comment: Yes, I cannot see any controls behind it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that WinForms only allow "fake transparency", 
By this definition, they are drawing the Parent object on the background of the child object.

Therefore, where I wanted to draw one chart on top of another, I needed to do the following:

```
chart1.Parent = chart2;
chart2.Parent = chart3;
```

Comment: That is nesting the charts. Why would you do that?? using overlaid chartareas is the way to go. And yes, as posted 10000 times: no transparency for overlapping controls, only for nested ones. If you want to see controls, why not put them over the chart so you can actually use them?